# ping one device after the other and check availability

Tags: bash, if-statement, for-loop, raspberry-pi, sendmail

I want to run a bash-script on my raspi.
The script's purpose is to check one device in my network for availability (with ping).

If this device is responding, script should end.
If it's not responding it has to go further and check the availability of 3 specific devices: if one device of that 3 is responding, then send a mail; if none of these devices is responding, then do nothing.

I hope it is recognizable what I've done so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=(192.168.xxx.xxx 192.168.xxx.xxx)
ping -c 1 192.168.xxx.xxx

if [$? -eq 0]; then exit 0
else

for devices in "${array[@]}"

do ping -c 1 $devices &> /dev/null

   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then exit 0

   fi
fi

done

/usr/sbin/sendmail foo@bar.com < /home/pi/scripts/email.txt
```

I'm pretty stuck right now, because my script skills are frightening bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=(192.168.xxx.xxx 192.168.xxx.xxx)
# a way to simplify first if:
ping -c 1 192.168.xxx.xxx && exit 0

for devices in "${array[@]}"; do

  # you want send mail if ping is ok
  if ping -c 1 $devices &> /dev/null; then
     /usr/sbin/sendmail foo@bar.com < /home/pi/scripts/email.txt
     exit 0
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Two errors in your code:

1. `if [$? -eq 0]; then` should be `if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then`
2. The `fi` before done should be moved outside the for loop.

Example:

```
array=(192.168.xxx.xxx 192.168.xxx.xxx)
ping -c 1 192.168.xxx.xxx

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
    exit 0
else
    for devices in "${array[@]}";do 
        ping -c 1 $devices &> /dev/null
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            exit 0
        fi
    done
fi
```

Suggested improvements:

1. Double quoting your variables is a good practice
2. Use of `if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then` is better than `if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then` in bash